# pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', u'[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Tags: python, database, odbc, ini, configparser

I am getting,  self.cnxn = pyodbc.connect(self.connStr)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', u'[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') while connecting to sql-server database.I am reading the server information,username,password of the database from the .ini file.But i am not able to connect to the db.Can anyone help me to resolve this?(Refer the Below Code)

```
def connectDB(self):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('databaseconnect.ini')
    DBconnect='DatabaseConnection'
    self.server = config[DBconnect]['server']
    self.database = config[DBconnect]['database']
    self.username = config[DBconnect]['username']
    self.password = config[DBconnect]['password']
    self.connStr = config[DBconnect]['connStr']
    self.cnxn = pyodbc.connect(self.connStr)
    self.cursor = self.cnxn.cursor()
```