# How to resolve pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', u'[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0)

Tags: python, database, odbc, ini, configparser

I am getting,pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', u'[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') while connecting to sql-server database.I am reading the server information,username,password of the database from the .ini file.But i am not able to connect to the db.Can anyone help me to resolve this?(Refer the Below Code)

```
databaseconnect.ini

[DatabaseConnection]
server=192.167.169.107
database=intdb
username=user3
password=laset$
connStr=DRIVER=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1;SERVER='+self.server+';DATABASE='+self.database+';'+ 'UID='+self.username+';PWD='+ self.password+';Port=1433

def connectDB(self):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('databaseconnect.ini')
    DBconnect='DatabaseConnection'
    self.server = config[DBconnect]['server']
    self.database = config[DBconnect]['database']
    self.username = config[DBconnect]['username']
    self.password = config[DBconnect]['password']
    self.connStr = config[DBconnect]['connStr']
    self.cnxn = pyodbc.connect(self.connStr)
    self.cursor = self.cnxn.cursor()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', u'\[HYT00\] \[unixODBC\]\[Microsoft\]\[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server\]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175589/pyodbc-operationalerror-hyt00-uhyt00-unixodbcmicrosoftodbc-driver-1)

Comment: This appears to be a copy+paste of your prior question. Please do not duplicate questions if you do not get an answer.